# Se debe crear una función lambda en AWS por endpoint?

Tags: nodejs, aws, lambda

Tengo los siguientes módulos: Usuarios, Pqr, Crm. En total suman 25 endpoints.

Debo crear una función lambda en aws por cada endpoint? (guardar usuario, editar usuario ....)

O seria mejor crear una función lambda por cada modulo?

Answer (score 1):

Respuesta corta: SI, mejor una lambda por cada endpoint

Respuesta larga:

Las lambdas son funciones cortas, cuyo tiempo de ejecución tiende a ser mínimo.

Podrías aglutinar varios endpoints en una misma lambda, pero ello provocaría varios efectos adversos:

- Acoplamiento innecesario: La Lambda debería conocer las rutas a los diferentes endpoints para saber qué es lo que debe devolver en cada momento. Esta situación le resta flexibilidad al sistema, puesto que resulta más costoso y complicado hacer cambios en el sistema.
- Lambda más compleja: Al tener que hacer frente a diferentes situaciones, el código de la Lambda, irremediablemente, va a a acabar siendo más complejo. Esto puede provocar que, al corregir errores en un endpoint, aparezcan otros nuevos en otros endpoints. Es lo que tiene reutilizar código. Para cada cambio que hagas vas a tener que probar concienzudamente todos los endpoints a los que atiende esta lambda.
- Lambda más cara: Esto suele ser un poco resultado del punto anterior, al ser la lambda más compleja, su tiempo de ejecución también tenderá a crecer. Esto provoca que la lambda sea más cara y que, en situaciones de estrés (muchas peticiones), el sistema será capaz de atender menos peticiones.

Por otro lado, piensa que las Lambdas pueden tener diferentes *layer*. Un *layer* o capa no es más que un paquete de código que se carga en la lambda y que la provee de funciones y utilidades.

Es decir, si una serie de lambdas necesitan una infraestructura común, es posible mover todo ese código a un *layer*, entonces puedes cargar ese *layer* en todas las lambdas que lo necesiten y así evitas tener que duplicar código innecesariamente.

La ventaja entre usar capas y sobrecargar una lambda es que las capas permiten que el código de la Lambda sea lo más simple y conciso posible. El código de la capa lo puedes probar tranquilamente en local antes de subirlo y con eso garantizar su correcto funcionamiento.

Un par de detalles sobre las capas:

- El tamaño de las capas cuenta para los límites de tamaño de las lambas
- Puedes tener diferentes capas en una misma lambda, está diseñado así para que puedas especializar cada capa en vez de crear capas sobrecaradas